# Access pass-through query to Oracle using WITH

Tags: sql, ms-access, oracle11g, odbc

I tried to run this in TOAD and sqldeveloper is ok, but when I run in Access with passthrough query I got an error: 
"pass-through query with returnsRecords property"

hereby the code

```
With T1 as (select * from baasa), 
T2 as (select * from lalala), 
T4 as  (select * from babab)
select distinct T1.C11 as something, T4.C5 as somewhere, T2.C2 as what
from T1,T2,T4
Where T1.C11=T4.C5 and T1.C10=T2.C2
```

or in fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/84c06/2
can anyone help me?

Comment: I'll admit that I haven't worked with Oracle for a *long* time, but I don't think you've given us enough of your query to identify the problem. I know for certain that Access pass-through queries can use Common Table Expressions on SQL Server, so I don't see why you shouldn't be able to use them on Oracle too. Just to confirm: Your query *does* return records, and the `Returns Records` property of the pass-through query is set to `Yes`, correct?

Comment: it returned records when i use sqldeveloper but when i used access i got this erro: "pass-through query with returnsRecords property".  may i know how to set it to yes or no? thank

Comment: Your question as stated makes no sense. Your SQL fails with "ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword". Check the SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/84c06/1) to verify. Also, "pass-through query with returnsRecords property" is not a valid Access error message. We cannot help you if you do not tell us what you are *really* doing.

Comment: @GordThompson i added there http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/84c06/2 , im sorry for confusion.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name its TOAD lol..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your (amended) query works fine in SQL Server 2008 R2, and it also works fine as an Access pass-through query to same. Verify that the `Returns Records` property of the query is set to `Yes` (as seen below) and try running the pass-through query again. As I said in my initial comment to your question, if it works for SQL Server then I see no reason why it shouldn't work for Oracle.

[image: ptq.png]

Comment: @Xarxas Did you click the "Pass-Through" button in the "Query Type" section of the ribbon bar? (Take another look at the screenshot, above. It's the button highlighted in yellow.)

Comment: in ODBC connection Str what should i fill in ( im sorry for lots of stupid questions)

Comment: @Xarxas Take a look at the Microsoft article [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/process-sql-on-a-database-server-by-using-a-pass-through-query-HA010206488.aspx).

Comment: and what strange is also, when i tried to import the tables into my local database it works fine. but when i tried to connect via ODBC to oracle it didnt work... :(

Comment: it works now:) i changed it, removed the "with"
so the code is :
select * from (select * from table1) where something. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure your query has a syntax error: there's no SELECT nor FROM clause before the WHERE clause...

Comment: im sorry i added there.